# Change value css property after drag element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have two videos: video 1 is below video 2. When I move the draggable element, I want to display part of the video 1.

I found an example which runs with a picture, and I tested this with videos but it's not working fine.

The fiddle with the picture : https://jsfiddle.net/kr64c5Lf/11/

The fiddle with videos : https://jsfiddle.net/1co0x58v/9/

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    $("#draggable").draggable();

    jQuery("#droppable").droppable({
      drop: function (event, ui) {

        debugger;

        var pos = ui.draggable.offset();
        var dPos = $(this).offset();

        // Pixxel value of positions
        var elementTopPosition = pos.top - dPos.top;
        var elementLeftPosition = pos.left - dPos.left;

        console.log(elementTopPosition);
        console.log(elementLeftPosition);

        $("#video1").css("max-width", elementLeftPosition);
        $("#video1").css("max-height", elementTopPosition);
        $("#video1").css("overflow", "hidden");
        $("#video1").css("z-index", "100");

        // Getting parent element height and width
        var parentWidth = jQuery("#droppable").width();
        var ParentHeight = jQuery("#droppable").height();

        // Coverting to percentage
        var topInPercentage = (100 * elementTopPosition) / ParentHeight;
        var leftInPercentage = (100 * elementLeftPosition) / parentWidth;

        $("#draggable").css({top: topInPercentage + '%', left: leftInPercentage + '%'});

      }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="mediaplayer">
      <video id="video1">
          <source src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <div id="droppable">
        <div id="draggable">Barre</div>
      </div>
      <video id="video2">
         <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .mediaplayer video, .mediaplayer .polyfill-video {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       height: 180px;
       width: 320px;
    }
    #draggable {
       width: 320px;
       padding: 2px 5px;
       cursor: pointer;
       color: #000;
       z-index: 100;
    }
    #droppable {
       position: relative;
       width: 320px;
       height: 180px;
       padding: 10px;
       z-index: 100;
    }
```

Comment: Could expand upon what the issue is, what needs to be "working". It's not clear what the issue is here.

Comment: Thank's Twisty.
I would like run two identical videos, but which one have effects in more. By moving the draggable element, I want to compare videos.

Comment: Are both videos visible upfront or does the act of dragging make the 2nd video appear? What in this is not working? How do they line up, horizontally, vertically?

Comment: Looking over things, I added `containment` like so: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1co0x58v/10/ This helps keep the draggable to a reasonable area. Also means that video one percentage is better.

Comment: Thank's a lot Twisty, I like your fiddle. Just the problem is the fact that when the video which is down appears, she it seems full and resized. I look for how I can not resize the video and to keep its original size while showing a part of the video of the bottom, and not in its total.

Comment: So you want `video1` to remain 100% width, yet pull it down to cover `video2`, correct? This would be changing the `margin` or `top` values instead of the `height` or `width`.

Comment: Yes, I think it's that, but like I have a  bad english I prefere put online pictures to explain. Thank's Twisty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt that using Draggable and Droppable was working against you. Here is a solution with Slider:

**Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1co0x58v/13/

**HTML**

```
<div class="player">
  <div id="barre"></div>
  <div class="mediaplayer">
    <video id="video1">
      <source src="http://html5videoformatconverter.com/data/images/happyfit2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    <video id="video2">
      <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Time</th>
      <td>
        <input class="time-slider" type="range" disabled value="0" step="any" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input value="Play" type="button" class="play" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input value="Stop" type="button" class="pause" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Mute</th>
      <td>
        <input class="muted" type="checkbox" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Volume</th>
      <td>
        <input class="volume-slider" type="range" value="1" max="1" step="0.01" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.player {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 320px;
  max-width: 900px;
  min-width: 320px;
}

.mediaplayer {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  width: 320px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.mediaplayer video,
.mediaplayer .polyfill-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
}

.mediaplayer video#video1 {
  top: -180px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#barre {
  height: 160px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#barre").slider({
  orientation: "vertical",
  range: "min",
  min: 0,
  max: 180,
  value: 180,
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    var offset = 180;
    if (ui.value == 0) {
      $("#video1").css("top", "0px");
    } else {
      $("#video1").css("top", "-" + ui.value + "px");
    }
  }
});
```

This makes use of the absolute positioning and the `top` value. Since the height of `mediaplayer` is `180px`, I hide `video1` by moving this into the overflow (which is hidden). When the slider is moved from the Top downward, it goes from a value of 180 and descends. This allows me to slide `video1` down and up with ease.

**Update**

Again, I still think Slider is a better method here. After seeing your update, I created this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/1co0x58v/25/

**HTML**

```
<div class="mediaplayer">
    <div id="barre"></div>
    <div class="viewport">
      <video id="video1" autoplay>
        <source src="https://3dprintmaker.com/perso/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
    </div>
    <video id="video2" autoplay>
      <source src="https://3dprintmaker.com/perso/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.viewport {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.mediaplayer video,
.mediaplayer .viewport video,
.mediaplayer .polyfill-video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 180px;
  width: 320px;
}

#barre {
  height: 0px;
  width: 320px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#barre .ui-slider-handle {
  background-image: url("https://3dprintmaker.com/perso/player/barre.jpg");
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 15px;
  height: 185px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#barre").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 320,
    value: 160,
    slide: function(e, ui){
    $(".viewport").css("width", (ui.value + 7) + "px");
    }
  });
```

To achieve what you were looking for, I created a wrapper div with the class `viewport`, that become the view able area of `video1`. Overflow is allowed and hidden. So now all we have to do is adjust the width of the viewport and `video1` will appear to overlay `video2`.

To make the handle, we just use some CSS. Set the handle width and height as needed and give it the image background you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefere use picture than text to represent the draggable element.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5mDO.jpg)

[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdZPH.jpg)

Comment: The second video in this exemple is the first in sepia.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for your help Twisty. I am going to see your tests.
For my part, I moved forward and I obtained the result which I wished, but I have some bugs.

https://jsfiddle.net/1co0x58v/20/

**HTML**

```
    <div class="player">
      <div class="mediaplayer">
         <div id="droppable">
            <video id="video1" autoplay>
               <source src="../video2.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
            <div id="draggable"><img src="http://3dprintmaker.com/perso/player/barre.jpg" /></div>
         </div>
         <video id="video2" autoplay>
             <source src="../video1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
         </video>
       </div>
     </div>
```

**CSS**

```
     .player {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 320px;
     }
    .mediaplayer {
       position: relative;
       height: 0;
       width: 320px;
       padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    }
    .mediaplayer video, .mediaplayer .polyfill-video {
       position: absolute;
       top: 0;
       left: 0;
       height: 180px;
       width: 320px;
    }
    #draggable {
       width: 320px;
       cursor: pointer;
       color: #000;
       z-index: 100;
    }
    #droppable{
       position: relative;
       width: 320px;
       height: 180px;
    }
    #video1{
      width: 320px;
      height: 180px;
    }
    #video2{
      width: 320px;
      height: 180px;
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
    $("#draggable").draggable({
       containment: "#video2"
    });

    jQuery("#droppable").droppable({
       drop: function(event, ui){
       debugger;
       $("#droppable").mousemove(function(e)
       {
          var calcul1 = e.pageX;
          var calcul2 = calcul1-15;
          $("#droppable").css("width", calcul1+"px");
          $("#droppable").css("overflow", "hidden");
          $("#droppable").css("z-index", "100");
          $("#draggable").css("left", calcul2+"px");
          $("#draggable").css("top", "0px");
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your fiddle is very good Twisty, thanks again for your help. 
It's almost finish, I try to debug the problem with the picture when I drag, but it's difficult and I have a problem in the droppable zone at the ends.
jsfiddle.net/1co0x58v/22

Comment: This is much different than you presented in your original post. You can do the same, using Slider as I suggested. You can even make the Marker large like that, such that it's dividing the two videos.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I believe it answers your question and I hope that you will mark it as such.

Comment: It's just what I want, thank you very much Twisty. I'm glad that you helped me.